# Is there any way to get a Firefox version with FireBug and FirePath

Tags: firebug, mozilla, firepath

I know that the support for FireBug ended years ago and that it has been moved into the Developer tools. Though, is there any possible way out there to get work again?

Sadly i don't have a machine any longer with Firefox and these two addons installed on it. If so, i already found a solution to get it work again. But i need to start from scratch again. Honestly, i don't see any way to get it work again because it was removed from the addons search of FireFox.

Anyway. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug only worked on in Firefox versions up to 56, because starting from [Firefox 57 only WebExtensions][6] are supported and Firebug is based on different APIs.
The last version of Firebug was 2.0.19. Just search for it in your favorite search engine and you'll find where to download it. The same accounts for FirePath.

So, you would need to [download Firefox 56](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/56.0.2/) and [Firebug 2.0.19](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5445-firebug.html).

Having said that, I recommend *not* trying to switch back to these very outdated versions. They have security issues and it doesn't make sense to develop on an outdated browser, which lacks any newer web technology.

The Firefox DevTools already provide some support for XPath and CSS selector searches like FirePath did. Just open the Inspector, [press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to focus the search field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML#Searching) and start typing your XPath or CSS selector.
Furthermore, they provide an [$x() helper function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#$x) allowing to return all elements matching an XPath.